# AWS Cognito Verification Code length change

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

AWS Cognito is sending 6 digits verification code for mobile/email verification.

Is there any way to ***customize the size*** of the verification code?
*Ex: changing it to **4** digits*

I went through the AWS documentation but couldn't find any solution.

*Thanks in Advance*

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot change the internal logic of cognito.

However, you can create your own logic to verify users. 
You can create a pre signup lambda to send random 4 digit code to email of the newly created user (you can store the temporary code in custom user attribute which is hidden from user or in dynamodb table with userid for comparison later). Then create another lambda which has [AdminUpdateUserAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUpdateUserAttributes.html) privileges in the role. This lambda will get triggered by apigateway which will take the 4 digit code as input. Then compare this code to the one you stored earlier. If it matches, make the AdminUpdateUserAttributes call and mark the user verified.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah, but in that case, we need to do manually(storing and comparing).

Comment: Yes. You cannot alter internal logic of cognito. You can only implement your own in its place.

Comment: @NinadGaikwad . What do you mean "post signup lambda" ? Is it Lambda trigger or lambda function which we need to define?

Comment: @stay_hungry My mistake, it's actually called `pre-signup` lambda. And you can find it under triggers in your user pool settings.

Comment: @NinadGaikwad. Thanks for ur information. In this way, how we can implement resend code option? Because email is sent in pre singup lambda trigger.

Comment: @stay_hungry You can create another lambda for that or write your pre signup lambda in such a way that it can handle both types of invocations. Write conditional statement to read event and call different function depending on the event content.

Comment: Is AWS Cognito always send 6 digits? or can that vary?