# Is there a way to change the length of email confirmation code in AWS Cognito Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Currently the AWS Cognito supports only 6 digits confirmation code and there is no configuration to change this.
But in some cases, there is a need to change the length of this confirmation code length, say to 4 or 8, for the convenience of the users who signs up or as a better security measure.
I'd like to know if there is a way to do this via lambda function trigger for Cognito or whatever.
Thank.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure whether you want to use Email or Phone Verification. See this doc topic for more information.

[Email or Phone Verification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-email-phone-verification.html)

Using the Cognito API, you cannot change the length of the verification code. See - [AWS Cognito Verification Code length change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479647/aws-cognito-verification-code-length-change)

Comment: smac2020, thanks for your kind answer. Yes, I do know that it's impossible to change the code length by configuration. What I'd like to know is if there is a WORKAROUND by using lambda functions.