# Is there a way to change the length of the Mfa authorization codes for AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I’m working on an AWS project that uses Cognito for authentication, and the client asked for sms verification but also he wants the code to be of 5 numbers length.

I’ve found a lot of documentation on how to customize de sms message text on AWS console and with lambdas, but I haven’t been able to find something about changing the verification code size.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Cognito Verification Code length change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479647/aws-cognito-verification-code-length-change)

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer in another question: [AWS Cognito Verification Code length change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479647/aws-cognito-verification-code-length-change).

Seems that is not possible with configuration, but it can be done customizing the authorization flow with lambda.

Comment: Kudos for sharing the solution to your problem. This is the way! :-)